# Swift json deserialize

Tags: json, ios, swift

Olá, tenho o seguinte código para deserializar um json:

```
let urlFinal = URLSERVIDOR+"/Geral/consulta?idcliente=\(id)"
        let jsonUrl = urlFinal
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                falha()
                return
            }

            do {
                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
                let J = jsonData as! NSDictionary
                let us = J["ServicoCliente"]
                var mstemp = [servicocliente]()
                mstemp <-- us
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    sucesso(servs: mstemp)
                });
            } catch _ {
                print("##")
                falha()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

Ele funciona muito bem, mas em alguns jsons específicos ele vem apresentando erro, falhando na linha

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Eu uso a biblioteca jsonHelper, mas ele falha antes mesmo na parte que utiliza ela (var mstemp = servicocliente; mstemp <-- us).

Não consigo encontrar o motivo da falha, o json que estão baixando é o seguinte:

```
{"ServicoCliente":[{"id":"190","cliente":"229","enderecoFavoritos":"41","servicoProfissional":"191","ind_estado_cliente":"A","ind_estado_profissional":"","profissional_id":"230","profissional_nome":"Athila Zuma","servicotipo_nome":"ClÃ­nica / Hospital","servicosubtipo_nome":"Consulta","dta_inc_alt":"2016-10-24 20:59:43.473","ind_finalizado":"N"},{"id":"192","cliente":"229","enderecoFavoritos":"46","servicoProfissional":"194","ind_estado_cliente":"A","ind_estado_profissional":"","profissional_id":"240","profissional_nome":"Max","servicotipo_nome":"shop","servicosubtipo_nome":"Tosa ","dta_inc_alt":"2016-11-03 00:54:58.682","ind_finalizado":"N"},{"id":"193","cliente":"229","enderecoFavoritos":"47","servicoProfissional":"195","ind_estado_cliente":"O","ind_estado_profissional":"O","profissional_id":"243","profissional_nome":"Ultra","servicotipo_nome":"ClÃ­nica / Hospital","servicosubtipo_nome":"EmergÃªncia 24H","dta_inc_alt":"2016-11-05 11:12:34.536","ind_finalizado":"Y"}]}
```

Como poderia obter essas informações sem causar esse erro?

Comment: Talvez seja pq esse json não está usando o unicode correto para escapar alguns caracteres, já tentou enviar o json sem esses chars especiais?

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso ao server, sera que tem como tratar isso no swift? @JanCássio

Comment: Athila, tem um repositório no GitHub demonstrando o funcionamento de um app todo em JSON. Acho que pode ser bastante útil para você. Veja: [https://github.com/ethanwang/Artistry](https://github.com/ethanwang/Artistry) Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar:

```
    public class func serializeJSON(dictionary: NSDictionary) -> NSData? {
        var data: NSData? = nil
        do {
        data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("SMCore ->  Error JSON Serialization: \(error) --<<<", terminator: "")
        }
        return data
    }
```